# How to permanently cache data (Images) loaded?

Tags: java, android

My app loads and display thumbnails of top movies from a server via API. I don't  want to query server and reload it every-time, I use glide to display images from server url.

How do i implement this image caching so that app uses previously loaded data, even if its offline.

**Is there any library** or do i have to store the images using **sqlite** and retrieve it ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you read https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics or https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation ??

Answer (score 1):

If you use Glide to load the images, there is an extremely simple one-liner to cache all images.

Simple add '.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)' to your Glide loading, and it'll cache the image, and use it even if you're offline.

So it could look like this:

```
Glide.with(context)
       .load(imageUrl)
       .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
       .into(target);
```

You should take a look at the introduction to Glide, on their official github repo. It mentions a lot of details about how it works.